# Intersecting paths in Raphael

Tags: javascript, path, raphael

I am trying to found out if two paths are intersected in Raphael. I have tried getBBox() but that returns the coordinates of a box around the path itself. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, there. Did my answer (top voted one below) solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers may have been for an earlier version of Raphael. The API now includes a [pathIntersection](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathIntersection) method which returns an array of intersecting points. You can simply check the length of the return value.

Comment: The API may have the function, but I have never seen it work when using it with two lines ( unclosed paths ).  This has been broken for quite a while, I have seen posts in the google group going back to 2012.  I am guessing the function works as intended, but should be called areaIntersection.

Answer (score 3):

[Bruteforce method](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getPointAtLength). Get all the points for the two path and see if two points are the same.

I made you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BJQLR/2/) but maybe you should come up with a better comparing solution. Depending on how long your paths are, this can be heavy.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, '100%', '100%');

var path1 = paper.path("M0 0L100 100");
var path2 = paper.path("M100 0L0 100");

var array1 = new Array();
var array2 = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < path1.getTotalLength(); i++) {
    array1.push(path1.getPointAtLength(i));
}

for(var i = 0; i < path2.getTotalLength(); i++) {
    array2.push(path2.getPointAtLength(i));
}

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < array2.length; k++) {
        // the threshold +-1 is important!
        if(array1[i].x < ( array2[k].x + 1 ) &&
           array1[i].x > ( array2[k].x - 1 )) {
               if(array1[i].y < ( array2[k].y + 1 ) &&
                  array1[i].y > ( array2[k].y - 1 )) {
                   alert('yeah'); // uncomment this. It will alert 4 times.
               } 
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Really handy jsfiddle. I modified it so that you can see how and where the intersects are detected and choose the threshold and see tradeoffs between accuracy and intensity. I set it to 10 pixels default as that's a clear one to see how it works. http://jsfiddle.net/BJQLR/20/ If you wanted something to test distance from each point by circle rather than square make some 'square over hypotenuse' maths based on difference between co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to implement something yourself as it seems Raphael doesn't provide this sort of functionality. Here's a [circle intersection example](http://zreference.com/circle-intersections-w-raphael/) that might help. [Here's something more specific](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/385751-bezier-curve-intersection/).

Before running your actual algo you probably want to check if the bounding boxes intersect. If they do, check actual paths.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) lovely intersection library. With that you can do stuff like this:

```
var shape1 = new Path(pathElement1),
    shape2 = new Path(pathElement2);

var inter = Intersection.intersectShapes(shape1, shape2);

    if(inter.points.length > 0) {
        // yes they intersect!
    }
```

The `inter` object in my example contains other good stuff to.